# Can't Install AzureADPreview

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I'm unable to install [AzureADPreview](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureADPreview/2.0.0.76) on my machine. When I run 'Install-Module -Name AzureADPreview' I get the error message:

> No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name 'AzureADPreview'

If I run 'Get-PSRepository' I get

> WARNING: Unable to find module repositories.

I have spent few hours trying to resolve this issue but to no avail. My first thought was maybe there was no provider setup but running 'Get-PackageProvider -ListAvailable' shows [image]

I thought maybe Nuget wasn't installed properly so I re-installed it using 'Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Verbose -Force' same problem. Interesting thing is I can find package using Chocolatey but AzureADPreview is not hosted there.

My machine is running Windows 10 with .Net Framework 4.6.2 installed.

Am I missing something really obvious?

Answer (score 1):

The had exactly the same problem on windows 10. I am behind a corp proxy.

Step 1: [System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials

Step 2: Register-PSRepository -Default

Step 3: Get-PSRepository

Hope this works for you too. It all started for me when I was trying to execute

Install-Module AzureADPreview

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, to install items from the Gallery requires the latest version of the PowerShellGet module, which is available in Windows 10, in **Windows Management Framework (WMF) 5.0**, or in the MSI-based installer (for **PowerShell 3 and 4**).

We can use PowerShell to view the version of WMF:

```
PS C:\windows> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.14393.693
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.14393.693
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Get WMF 5.0 or later, the PSVersion is the WMF version, my WMF version is 5.1.

Here is the requires of the AzureadPreview, please refer to [it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/gallery/readme).

Comment: As I said in my description I have Windows 10 so I already have the latest version of PowerShellGet. My PSVersion is 5.1.14393.953.

Comment: @mob1lejunkie  please try to register PSGallery with this command `Register-PSRepository -Default` Then try `Get-PSRepository`

Comment: @mob1lejunkie `Get-PSRepository` still WARNING: Unable to find module repositories?

Comment: Yes still the same warning.

Comment: @mob1lejunkie please try `get-module -Name Packagemanagement` and `get-packagesource`. is there something list in powershell?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138586/discussion-between-jason-ye-msft-and-mob1lejunkie).